# Oracle search array within JSON values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following stored in an Oracle database as JSON:

```
{
   value: [1,2,3]
}
```

The value can be of any type (strings, integers or arrays). How would I query if the type is array and if it contains a certain value?

In pseudocode:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME.value CONTAINS 2`

I can see how to query strings using Oracle functions such as `json_query` but cannot see how to run this specific type of query without selecting all data and searching on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `JSON_TABLE` in the `FROM`, defining the columns and then use it in `where` clause to filter rows.

```
--Test data
with t (id,j)
as
( select 1, TO_CLOB(
  '{
     value : [1,2,3]
   }') FROM DUAL
 ) 
--Test data ends--
select t.id,tbl.val FROM t cross join 
    json_table(j,'$.value[*]' columns (val varchar2(100) path '$') ) as tbl
where tbl.val = 2


    ID      VAL 
  ------  -------
     1      2
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I combine tbl.val with a bind (:val), the DB resets my connection and throws a generic error. Has anyone else experienced this? It works if I use literals though.